How to find a condition on $a,b,c$ such that solutions exist to a system of inequalities
How can I find a condition on $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R_{> 0}}$ such that there exist solutions $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$
$$
\begin{align}
ax-y-z&>0 \\
-x+by-z&>0 \\
-x-y+cz&>0 
\end{align}
$$
with $x,y,z>0$ too?
I have tried using matrices as one would with equalities but the inequalities don't transfer over as there is no notion of a vector being greater than another vector. How can I do this?

Each inequality determines a (open) half-space through the origin. When will have a non-trivial intersection?

Moo how did you reach this conclusion?

What does CAS mean?

Given the following system of inequalities:
$$
\begin{cases}
ax-y-z>0\\
-x+by-z>0\\
-x-y+cz>0\\
\end{cases}
$$
with $a,b,c>0$ and $x,y,z>0$, it's noted that:

adding $a$ times the second to the first inequality, we get $dy-z>0$, with $d:=\frac{ab-1}{a+1}>0$;

adding $a$ times the third to the first inequality, we get $-ey+z>0$, with $e:=\frac{a+1}{ac-1}>0$;

adding these last two inequalities we get $(d-e)y>0$, with $d-e>0$.


Therefore, this system of inequalities admits solutions when:
$$
\begin{cases}
a>0\\
b>0\\
c>0\\
d>0\\
e>0\\
d-e>0\\
\end{cases}
\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad
\boxed{a>0
\quad\land\quad
b>\frac{1}{a}
\quad\land\quad
c>\frac{a+b+2}{ab-1}\,}
$$
which are the conditions on the parameters required by OP.
